# looping through all records on the database

Tags: sql, vb.net

i revised the code a little from a friend

but it only display the first record how will i able to manipulate to loop through all records

anyone who could give correct answer in code will receive bounty thanks

Note:  `DisplayOfficeEquipmentList()`  is a sub that displays data on the database to the textboxes and comboboxes

```
Public Sub DisplayOfficeEquipmentList()
        Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
        "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        sqlconn.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        cmbCategory.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Category").ToString()
        cmbSubCategory.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_SubCategory").ToString()
        txtOEID.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_ID").ToString()
        txtName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Name").ToString()
        txtUser.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_User").ToString()
        cmbBrand.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Brand").ToString()
        cmbModel.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Model").ToString()
        txtSpecs.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Specs").ToString()
        txtSerialNo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_SerialNo").ToString()
        txtPropertyNo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_PropertyNo").ToString()
        txtMacAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_MacAddress").ToString()
        txtStaticIP.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Static_IP").ToString()
        txtVendor.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Vendor").ToString()
        dtpPurchaseDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_PurchaseDate").ToString()
        txtWarrantyStatus.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_WarrantyStatus").ToString()
        txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").ToString()
        txtStatus.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Status").ToString()
        cmbDeptCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Dept_Code").ToString()
        cmbLocationCode.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Location_Code").ToString()
        txtRemarks.Text = dt.Rows(0)("OE_Remarks").ToString()
        sqlconn.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click



    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click

    End Sub
```

Comment: Add the rest of the code. All the stuff is inside DisplayOfficeEquipmentList()

Comment: @CarlosLanderas here is it sir

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop the lines, you are getting the values of the row at index 0( Just one row).

Use foreach:

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
 //Get values of row
}
```

**EDIT:** In vb.net it would be something like this:

```
For Each filarow As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim OE_ID As String = filarow("OE_ID").ToString
            Dim txtName As String = filarow("OE_NAME").ToString
Next
```

By the way, it seems you are filling textboxes, so the values will change at the next loop. Maybe you should use another control like a ListBox

Comment: You dont need the Tables just dt.rows

Comment: Oh, saw you changed it now. :)

Comment: Yes, I thought he was using Dataset, changed when I saw it was Datatable. Coding without IDE right now xD

Comment: I updated my answer with vb.net code. Just include the rest of the fields

Comment: Consider using another control like a ListBox. When you iterate the rows the textbox will show the contents of the last row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the logic that retrieve data from the logic that shows that data.
First add a method that load your datatable

```
Private Function LoadData() as DataTable

    Using sqlconn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
                                 "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        sqlconn.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile", sqlconn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        return dt
    End Using
End Function
```

Then in the buttons click pass the datatable and the rownumber to display to the DisplayOfficeEquipmentList

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
     if currentRow + 1 >= dt.Rows.Count Then
        Return
     End if
     currentRow = currentRow + 1
     DisplayOfficeEquipmentList(dt, currentRow)
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
     if currentRow - 1 < 0 Then
        Return
     End if
     currentRow = currentRow - 1
     DisplayOfficeEquipmentList(dt, currentRow)
End Sub
```

and in the DisplayOfficeEquipmentList refer to the row passed by the buttons click

```
Public Sub DisplayOfficeEquipmentList(ByRef dt as DataTable, ByVal rowNum as INteger)
    Dim row as DataRow
    row = dt.Rows(rowNum)
    cmbCategory.Text = row("OE_Category").ToString()
    cmbSubCategory.Text = row("OE_SubCategory").ToString()
    ....
End Sub
```

For this to work, you need to call the LoadData somewhere when you show your form (Load event?) and you should set the currentRow as a form global level variable

Comment: sir im having a problem calling the function to the main form but my global variable is working now

Comment: Which problem? Which function? Any error message? I could help but I need more context